maximum channel power calculation in "TIDA-010048" Channel-to-Channel Isolated Analog Input Module
according to TI document " https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiduen8/tiduen8.pdf?ts=1731778638924 " they say:
in page (2) Table 1. Key System Specifications
Power supply part for 2-wire transmitter per
channel:
Supply voltage 25 VDC
Overvoltage limit 33 VDC
Overcurrent and short-circuit limit 25 mA
and then page 4 (2.2 Design Considerations):
"Every isolated maximum channel power can provide the field side to 1.25 W."
shouldn't it be 25V × 0.025A = 0.625W ??

Looking at Schematic — TIDA-010048 shows R4 which sets the current limit in on the TPS26625 Efuse has the value 267k.
The Bill of materials (BOM) — TIDA-010048 confirms R4 has the value 267 kΩ.
The TPS26625 datasheet shows that the R4 value of 267 kΩ will result in a current limit of 0.025 mA (typical).
Therefore, it does look like an error in the Design Guide: TIDA-010048 which should say the maximum channel power which can be provided is 0.625 W, rather than 1.25 W.
Consider using the Submit Document Feedback link to report an error in the design guide document.
